# GRUB2 and PXE: error: no suitable video mode found

Tags: linux-kernel, boot, grub2, pxe

I am building a diskless Debian 11 image that will load over PXE; that part mostly works, but I'm seeing this annoying message during boot:

```
error: no suitable video mode found.
Booting in blind mode
```

The system still comes up and the text console works, so it isn't a blocker, but being a perfectionist, I would like to fix it. This is my `grub.cfg` from under `/srv/tftp` - my goal is to have a completely simple boot menu:

```
# cat boot/grub/grub.cfg
terminal_input console
terminal_output console
set gfxmode=text
set timeout=5

menuentry 'Boot Debian 11' {
  linux /debian11/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-22-amd64 console=tty0 ip=dhcp root=/dev/nfs ro nfsroot=192.168.50.111:/image/debian11,vers=3,nolock panic=60 ipv6.disable=1 rootwait
  initrd /debian11/boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-22-amd64
}
```

The error shows up after the kernel starts, so presumably I need to change/add a kernel parameter - but which?